# Clarification of jQuery "wrapper" object

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a doubt about the jQuery core. From the docs and a couple of books I get:

```
var obj = $("div");
```

Which returns a wrapper object AKA a collection of selected DOM elements with additional methods (correct me if I'm wrong). I've read the jQuery function `$()` returns a wrapper object, or does it really return a copy of jQuery plus a collection of wrapped elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns an instance of a jQuery object, wrapping the elements you selected with your CSS selector (in this case, a jQuery object wrapping all the divs in the document).

jQuery isn't something that is "copied" - it is behavior that is wrapped around elements in the DOM.

```
var jqDivs = $("div");
var jqButtons = $("button");
var jqSubmitButton = $("button#submit");
```

Those 3 vars reference 3 different objects.  All of them implement the same jQuery behaviors, but they do it upon different elements.  jqDivs.hide() would hide the divs - jqButtons.hide() would hide the buttons, and jqSubmitButton.hide() would hide only the button with id=submit.

Answer (score 6):

The term "wrap" is a bit misleading to me. jQuery keeps references to elements matched by the supplied selector as numeric properties of the jQuery instance returned by the call, so:

```
var allTheDivs = $('div');
```

returns a jQuery object with references to all the divs in the document, and:

```
allTheDivs[0];  // or allTheDivs['0'];
```

is a reference to the first one. So if you then do:

```
allTheDivs.hide();
```

it calls the *hide* method of the jQuery instance *allTheDivs* which cycles over all the referenced elements and hides them. But don't try:

```
allTheDivs['0'].hide()
```

as that will try to call *hide* on a DOM element, which probably won't exist so will restult in an error.